# Powershell can't remove file i just wrote

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I wanted to install git on an AWS EC2 Windows Server. So i used an Invoke-WebRequest to download the portable git exe

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.23.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe -UseBasicParsing -OutFile git.exe
```

But the Download got stuck and i terminated the session. Now i want to remove git.exe but for some reason i'm not allowed to.
I tried removing the file with:

```
Remove-Item .\git.exe
```

But i got an error message telling me i'm not allowd to

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\git.exe: Access to the path 'C:\git.exe' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item .\git.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\git.exe:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Do you run the script with administrator privileges?

Comment: Inspect the processes running using task manager, the window may have closed but the process or a child process can still be running holding on to the file handle. Or use process explorer from SysInternals to search for the file name to determine what process is still holding on to the file handle.

Comment: @AshamanKingpin: If that were the problem, the error message would be different: `The process cannot access the file '...\git.exe' because it is being used by another process`

Comment: @mklement0 Hmm, in hindsight, you are right.  Thanks

Comment: @worldgrep: This shouldn't happen; see if `Remove-Item -Force` helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the Invoke-WebRequest was not properly terminated and the stuck process still kept the file on lock. after restarting the server i was able to delete the file. Thanks for the suggestions and comments.